# Sequence asymptotically approaching multiplication by one constant if the previous term is odd and another if it is even

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

Say we have an integer sequence $G_k$, which in reality are the values of $$P(n)=5n^2+14n+1$$ for integers $n$ where $P(n)$ is a perfect square. Studying the values of this sequence, $$G_1=2\\
G_2=5\\G_3=21\\G_4=42\\G_5=152\\G_6=296$$ I noticed that the ratio between successive terms seems to approach two constants $a=3.53532228$ for the ratio between an odd and an even term and $b=1.93874$ for the ratio between an even and an odd term. Does anyone have any insight into this sequence? Particularly, is there a closed form expression for the values of these constants?

Comment: This is a slight variant of a generalized Pell equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation); after a suitable change of coordinates you can reduce to solving $z^2 - 5y^2 = 44$ which should be more or less straightforward if a bit tedious using the fact that $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right]$ has unique factorization and its group of units is generated by the golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: When trying to do this change of coordinates I only seem to be able to get it into the form $z^2-5y^2=-44/5$ ,which doesn't fit the form of that generalized pells equations. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm writing an answer with details. Multiply both sides by $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y^2 = 5x^2 + 14x + 1$ is a slight variant of a [(generalized) Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). We can try to turn it into a Pell equation: multiplying by $5$ gives

$$5y^2 = 25x^2 + 70x + 5 = (5x + 7)^2 - 44$$

so setting $z = 5x + 7$ gives the Pell equation

$$z^2 - 5y^2 = 44.$$

There are several ways to understand how to solve these; I'll use algebraic number theory. The LHS factors as

$$(z + y \sqrt{5})(z - y \sqrt{5}) = (u + v \phi)(u + v \varphi)$$

where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \varphi = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $u = z - y, v = 2y$. The point of doing this is that $\mathbb{Z}[\phi] = \mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ so we can appeal to standard facts about rings of integers. The LHS is the norm $N(z + \sqrt{5} y) = N(u + \phi v)$ and we can completely classify the algebraic integers with a fixed norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ by first understanding the factorization of $44$ up to units and then understanding the units (generated by $-1$ and $\phi$, which is a [fundamental unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_unit_(number_theory))).

$44$ is the norm of the element $\alpha = 7 + \sqrt{5} = 6 + 2 \phi = 2(3 + \phi)$, where $N(3 + \phi) = 11$ as expected. Because $11$ is prime, $3 + \phi$ is prime as an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$, so up to units the elements of norm $11$ are exactly $3 + \phi, 3 + \varphi$. The polynomial $x^2 - x - 1$ (whose roots are $\phi, \varphi$) is irreducible $\bmod 2$ which implies that $2$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi]$ and hence, up to units, the only element of norm $4$. All told, this gives that up to units the elements of norm $44$ are $6 + 2 \phi, 6 + 2 \varphi$, or equivalently $7 \pm \sqrt{5}$. Incidentally,

$$\boxed{ \frac{7 + \sqrt{5}}{7 - \sqrt{5}} = \frac{3 + \phi}{3 + \varphi} = 1.9387 \dots }$$

so we are getting closer to unraveling the mystery.

"Up to units" means the following: the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ of norm $44$ are exactly

$$\pm \phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi), \pm \phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi)$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (the $2n$ is because $N(\phi) = -1$). Since we're only looking at solutions to the Pell equation we can ignore the global sign of $-1$, and since $\phi = -\varphi^{-1}$ the conjugate of $\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi)$ is $\varphi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi) = \phi^{-2n} (6 + 2 \varphi)$ so up to conjugation we can restrict our attention to $n \ge 0$. This gives two infinite series of solutions, namely

$$\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi) = z_n + y_n \sqrt{5}$$

where

$$z_n = \frac{\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi) + \varphi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi)}{2} \approx \phi^{2n} (3 + \phi)$$
$$y_n = \frac{\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi) - \varphi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi)}{2 \sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{\phi^{2n} (3 + \phi)}{\sqrt{5}}$$

and

$$\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi) = z_n' + y_n' \sqrt{5}$$

where

$$z_n' = \frac{\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi) + \varphi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi)}{2} \approx \phi^{2n} (3 + \varphi)$$
$$y_n' = \frac{\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi) - \varphi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi)}{2 \sqrt{5}} \approx \frac{\phi^{2n} (3 + \varphi)}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

We're not quite done solving the original Pell equation: the values of $z, y$ above might a priori be half-integers and we need them to be integers, and furthermore we need $z$ to be congruent to $2 \bmod 5$.

Fortunately, because $6 + 2 \phi, 6 + 2 \varphi$ are divisible by $2$, after expanding out $\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \phi)$ or $\phi^{2n} (6 + 2 \varphi)$ we always get an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ divisible by $2$, which means its coefficients are divisible by $2$ so it can be written $z + y \sqrt{5}$ for integers $z, y$. So the $z, y$ values we get above are always integers. For example,

$$z_0 + y_0 \sqrt{5} = 6 + 2 \phi = 7 + \sqrt{5}$$
$$z_1 + y_1 \sqrt{5} = \phi^2 (6 + 2 \phi) = 8 + 10 \phi = 13 + 5 \sqrt{5}$$

and $z_0 = 7$ corresponds to the "degenerate" solution $G_0 = 0$. Next is to figure out when $z_n, z_n'$ are congruent to $2 \bmod 5$. This can be answered as follows: $z_n$ has initial conditions $z_0 = 7, z_1 = 13$ and satisfies a linear recurrence relation with characteristic polynomial $(t - \phi^2)(t - \varphi^2) = t^2 - 3t + 1$, which gives

$$z_{n+2} = 3 z_{n+1} - z_n.$$

Computing this recurrence $\bmod 5$ gives

$$z_0 \equiv 2 \bmod 5$$
$$z_1 \equiv 3 \bmod 5$$
$$z_2 \equiv 3 \cdot 3 - 2 \equiv 2 \bmod 5$$
$$z_3 \equiv 3 \cdot 2 - 3 \equiv 3 \bmod 5$$

so $z_n \bmod 5$ has period $2$ (this appears to be a lucky accident; $\phi^{2n} \bmod 5$ has period $10$) and we get that $z_n \equiv 2 \bmod 5$ iff $n$ is even, so only the even values of $n$ give solutions to our original equation. For example,

$$z_2 + y_2 \sqrt{5} = \phi^2 (13 + 5 \sqrt{5}) = 32 + 14 \sqrt{5}$$

and $z_2 = 32$ corresponds to your second solution $G_2 = 5$.

Next we want to understand when $z_n'$ is congruent to $2 \bmod 5$. $z_n'$ satisfies the same linear recurrence as $z_n$ above but with different initial conditions given by

$$z_0' + y_0' \sqrt{5} = 6 + 2 \varphi = 7 - \sqrt{5}$$
$$z_1' + y_1' \sqrt{5} = \phi^2(6 + 2 \varphi) = 8 + 2 \sqrt{5}$$

which gives $z_0' \equiv 2 \bmod 5, z_1' \equiv 3 \bmod 5$ as before, so $z_n \equiv z_n' \bmod 5$ which means $z_n' \equiv 2 \bmod 5$ iff $n$ is even as above. For example,

$$z_2' + y_2' \sqrt{5} = \phi^4 (6 + 2 \varphi) = 17 + 7 \sqrt{5}$$

which corresponds to your first solution $G_1 = 2$. Since $z_n$ and $z_n'$ have the same asymptotic growth rate $O(\phi^{2n})$, just differing by a multiplicative constant, they will always alternate in size, which gives the following closed form for your sequence $G$, alternating depending on parity:

$$\boxed{ G_{2n} = \frac{z_{2n} - 7}{5} \approx \phi^{4n} \frac{3 + \phi}{5} }$$
$$\boxed{ G_{2n-1} = \frac{z_{2n}' - 7}{5} \approx \phi^{4n} \frac{3 + \varphi}{5} }.$$

This means your two constants are

$$b = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{G_{2n}}{G_{2n-1}} = \frac{3 + \phi}{3 + \varphi} \approx 1.9387 \dots $$

as previously discussed, and

$$a = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{G_{2n+1}}{G_{2n}} = \boxed{ \phi^4 \frac{3 + \varphi}{3 + \phi} \approx 3.5353 \dots }.$$

Mystery solved!